# Derivation of Intensity of Wave

Tags: waves

A source tells me that the intensity of a wave is given by

$$I = 2\pi^2 f^2 A^2 \rho v , $$

where $f$ is the frequency of a wave, $A$ is the amplitude, $\rho$ is the density of the string and $v$ is the velocity of the wave. How can this be derived?

Comment: See: http://www.insula.com.au/physics/1279/L14.html

Comment: You can get a good idea from here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/powstr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could explain it here, but someone has already done it: http://physics.info/intensity/. The equation slightly differs from yours, but I think the reason lies in your way of looking at the Area $A$. So you might want to check that link.